# Examples of the prefix “co–” (instead of “ko–”) in German

Tags: spelling, prefix, latin

Gibt es im Deutschen Beispiele für die Verwendung von „co–“ als Präfix anstelle von „ko–“? Sind zumindest stets beide Verwendungen akzeptiert, auch wenn vielleicht eine Verwendung unüblich ist?

Beispiele für „ko–“ sind etwa:

> - Koproduktion
> - Kooperation
> - Koautor

Auf Wiki ist bei [„Kooperation“](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kooperation) keine Alternativschreibweise mit „co–“ aufgelistet, für [„Koautor“](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Koautor) hingegen schon.

Comment: _& Cie._ = _& Co._ = _und Compagnie_ ≈ _und Konsorten_, _GmbH & Co. KG_ = _Gesellschaft mit beschränkter Haftung und Compagnie Kommanditgesellschaft_. Da steckt natürlich _con/cum_ statt _co_ drin.

Comment: Das lateinische _c_ ist fast immer zu _k_ oder _z_ eingedeutscht, nur wenn ein Begriff über den Umweg einer anderen romanischen Sprache oder des Englischen stammt, findet sich das _c_ noch (und zwar auch für ursprünglich griechische Wörter mit Kappa), d.h. _co-_ wird nicht generell “geduldet”, vgl. _*Coproduktion_, _*Coproduction_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Transformation von *Co-* zu *Ko-* ist eine Anpassung von Fremdwörtern an die deutschen Rechtschreibkonventionen (zumindest seit 1901) und wird als solche in der Regel erst vorgenommen, wenn das Fremdwort zu einem gewissen Maße etabliert ist. Die Aufnahme in Wörterbücher erfolgt zu einem ähnlichen Zeitpunkt. Vermutlich legt auch teilweise der Wörterbuchautor dann aus Konsistenz die Schreibweise mit *Ko-* fest – Wörterbücher dienen ja gerade in solchen Fällen weniger dazu, einem zu verraten, wie das Wort überhaupt geschrieben werden kann, sondern vor allem dazu, eine Entscheidungshilfe zu bereiten.

Deswegen gibt es zurzeit wohl kein Wort auf *Co-* (wobei es sich auch um die entsprechende Vorsilbe handelt) in Wörterbüchern (zumindest ich konnte keines finden). Allerdings kann ich mir gut vorstellen, dass bei frischen Anglizismen die Variante mit *Co-* die dominierende ist (insbesondere wenn das komplette Wort und damit *Co-* noch Englisch ausgesprochen werden). Beispiele mit *Co-* hierfür fallen mir aber keine ein. Andererseits lässt z. B. der Duden als jeweils einzige Varianten *kompilieren* und *Compiler* zu (was auch nicht völlig unsinnig ist, da Letzteres Englisch ausgesprochen wird und Ersteres nicht).

Schließlich sei noch vermerkt, dass wohl nur noch Ablehner der Rechtschreibreform von 1901 durchgehend *Co-* nutzen.

Comment: Der Punkt mit der Aussprache von kompilieren scheint mir etwas wackelig. Das Wort hat [zwei Bedeutungen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kompilieren), und in der EDV-Version habe ich eher die englisch geprägte Aussprache im Ohr, also in etwa komp*ei*lieren.

Comment: @Matthias: Ich habe das Wort nun schon aus einer Vielzahl von Mündern gehört und diese Aussprache ist mir noch nie untergekommen. Ich würde auch vermuten, dass eher jemand *compilen* (kɔmˈpaɪ̯lən) sagt (was ich auch noch nie gehört habe). So oder so machen einige Leute, die es anders aussprechen, mein Argument zu nichte.

Answer (score 4):

Nicht immer wenn beide Versionen "erlaubt" sind, sind auch beide üblich; "Coautor" z. B. habe ich noch nie gesehen.

Der Duden kennt recht viele Beispiele anderer Wörter, die sowohl mit Co- als auch mit Ko- geschrieben werden dürfen:

- Cobalt/Kobalt (das Element)
- Cocain/Kokain
- Cochenille/Koschenille (ein Farbstoff)
- Coda/Koda (Auslaut einer Silbe)
- Codein/Kodein
- Coitus/Koitus
- Copilot/Kopilot

Da Co- und Ko- gleich ausgesprochen werden, hat sich anscheinend bei Fremdworten, die mit Co- beginnen, Ko- häufig als Alternative durchgesetzt. Interessant ist dieses Beispiel:

> *Coloradokäfer* ist eine alternative Bezeichnung für den Kartoffelkäfer (so kennen ihn die Deutschen), man darf laut Duden auch *Koloradokäfer* schreiben. Colorado als Bundesstaat hingegen hat keine alternative Schreibweise.

Wenn man sich nicht sicher ist, sollte Co- meistens die bessere Wahl bei Fremdwörtern sein, Ko- hingegen, wenn es sich um die Vorsilbe Ko- im Sinne von "zusammen" handelt (Koautor, Kooperation etc.).

Comment: Mich interessieren nur die Fälle, in denen „co–“ als Präfix verwendet wird, weswegen „Kobalt“, „Kokain“, „Koschenille“, „Koda“ und „Kodein“ sowie „Kolorado“ als Beispiele wegfallen. Trotzdem danke für den Rest.

Comment: "co bessere Wahl"?: Vielleicht trifft das zu, wenn man den Text speziell für Nichtmuttersprachler leichter verdaulich machen will. Für die Anhänger von "Electronic" und "Center" sieht es vielleicht auch schicker aus, ich würde in jedem Fall "Ko-" vorziehen.

Comment: Hallo guidot, "Electronic" und "Center" sind keine Beispiele für mit Co beginnende Worte. Mein Hinweis bezog sich allein auf mit Co/Ko beginnende Fremdworte, bei denen man unsicher ist welche Schreibweise geläufiger ist.